# Class 'Anonymous class derived from FirebaseAdapter' must be declared abstract in Adapter

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I've been getting an error (in my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) saying that the class must be declared abstract or implement method 'onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int) in 'Adapter', as well as Method does not override superclass on the "Override" just below that code.

However, I have no idea how to change my code to get rid of that error. Can someone please help me? I would really appreciate the help. Thank you!

```
DiaryActivity.java package com.shiminu1521462c.fyp_2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class DiaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;

    private RecyclerView mNotesList;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private DatabaseReference noteRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);


        mNotesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        mNotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mNotesList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mNotesList.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        }
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    private void loadData() {
        Query query = fNotesDatabase.orderByValue();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(

                NoteModel.class,
                R.layout.single_note_layout,
                NoteViewHolder.class,
                query

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final NoteViewHolder viewHolder, NoteModel model, int position) {
                final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

                fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("title") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("timestamp")) {
                            String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                            String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();

                            viewHolder.setNoteTitle(title);
                            //viewHolder.setNoteTime(timestamp);

                            GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                            viewHolder.setNoteTime(getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                            viewHolder.noteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(DiaryActivity.this, DiaryNewNoteActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };
        mNotesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.diary_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_note_button:
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(DiaryActivity.this, DiaryNewNoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is abstract.

If you want to extend it (as you do with an anonymous class in your method `loadData()`) you have to implement all its abstract methods. In that case apparently `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)`.

Add this method implementation to your anonymous class and you are done.

Comment: How do I add this method implementation? I tried putting onCreateViewHolder but it gave me the same error?